# Variable value for selecting plpgsql database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a procedure that receives parameters text with old and new names, I need to rename

```
ALTER DATABASE "OldName" RENAME TO "NewName";
```

Causes this

```
"3D000: database "OldName" does not exist"
```

I did not want to use execute because of security concerns...
Thanks

Comment: I don't think the semicolon is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The first Semi colon isn't required. The semi colon is used to terminate a statement which means you are running 2 statements in this instance.